# Visual Studio 2010 crashes when doing a Find all references

Tags: visual-studio-2010

**Complete EDIT [I messed up the previous question]**

A dialogue box shows up saying 
[title: find definition]
Preparing files for project '***_***'

Then it crashes half way.

I've tried to do it on two different computers, but it still crashes.

It works for other smaller solutions, but this is my biggest one.  about 16 projects.

Comment: Anything odd about these projects?  I have a solution with 70+ projects and can do find/replace across them no problem.  Are these replacements widespread/are there a lot of things to replace?

Comment: @Joe, nothing odd from what I can tell (I'm not the original developer).  I'm actually doing a 'Find All', within the Find and Replace dialogue.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586669/crash-when-using-find-in-files-in-a-large-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say Visual Studio crashes, does it just go into the "Not Responding" state or does it have a full on crash (wanting to submit error report etc) ?

The Not Responding state is normal if it is just that (ie. just let it keep running).

If you are still struggling, I have used Notepad++ to do search and replaces on huge projects. You would need to ensure all your projects are Checked-out first (if under source control) and then run a Find in Files search and replace over all your projects.

Sorry I have nothing more enlightening for you.

Comment: It has a full on crash, wanting to submit and error and restart the program (both computers).  I'll try to get a copy of NotePad++, thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still open to other solutions!

Comment: Do you actually open each file individually in Notepad++?  Or can you add all the projects to one solution, then search them all at one time?  Or can it actually open VS solutions?

Comment: When you open Notepad++, click on Search > Find in Files. A dialogue will appear allowing you to specify the term to search for and a directory to search through (find the directory you store all your projects in on your computer). Tick the In all sub-folders option. Hit "Find All". Alternatively "Replace in files" (!be careful with this one!) if wanting to do a search and replace. Optionally you can specify Filters if you only want to search through certain file types (by extension - eg. *.cs or *.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue; a Bug related to this is already present in MS Connect, but unfortunately no workaround is specified

[Visual Studio 2010 Crashes when "Find all Reference" is ran](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/630657/visual-studio-2010-crashes-when-find-all-reference-is-ran)