# Find in Entire Solution make Visual Studio crashed

Tags: replace, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, solution

**Update : apparently it's because my solution is too large ( the projects and assets it self ~56 GB). So after I switched to SSD Drive the crashes rarely happens. Well, perhaps the root problem was not this because it still crashed :) .

I am using MS Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows 8.1. 
I have a problem when trying to **Find** (Ctrl+F) and **Look In Entire Solution**, visual studio always crashed.

Anyone know what should I do?
Or maybe the workaround for this problem. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973359/visual-studio-2010-crashes-when-doing-a-find-all-references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched the drive to SSD Drive will help, the crashes still happen but the rate is low.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the solution, it worked for me.

From the menu bar: Build > Clean Solution

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I have tried it.
Well, this problem was fixed with magic. I dunno how, but it doesn't happen anymore :)